# Recommended pattern recognition technique for chess board

Tags: image-processing, image-recognition, chess, pattern-recognition

I'm trying to do an application which, among other things, is able to recognize chess positions on a computer screen from screenshots. I have very limited experience with image processing techniques and don't wish to invest a great amount of time in studying this, as this is just a pet project of mine.

Can anyone recommend me one or more image processing techniques that would yield me a good result?

The conditions are:

- The image is always crispy clean, no noise, poor light conditions etc (since it's a screenshot)
- I'm expecting a very low impact on computer performance while doing 1 image / second
- I've thought of two modes to start the process:

  - Feed the piece shapes to the program (so that it knows what a queen, king etc. looks like)
  - just feed the program an initial image which contains the startup position, from which the program can (after it recognizes the position of the board) pick each chess piece

  The process should be relatively easy to understand, as I don't have a very good grasp of image processing techniques (yet)

  I'm not interested in using any specific technology, so technology-agnostic documentation would be ideal (C/C++, C#, Java examples would also be fine).

Thanks for taking the time to read this, and I hope to get some good answers.

Comment: Screenshots from a computer?  Is there a reason you're not just interacting with the chess program somehow?  That would likely be much easier.

Comment: see http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/PlayChessWithAWebCam/Papers for resources on the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It' an interesting problem, but you need to specify a lot more than in your original question in order to find an acceptable answer.

On the input images: "screenshots" is quote vague a category. Can you assume that the chessboard will always be entirely in view? Will you have multiple views of the same board? Can you assume that no pieces will be partially or completely occluded in all views?

On the imaged objects and the capture system: will the same chessboard and pieces be used, under very similar illumination? Will the same lens/camera/digitization pipeline be used?

Comment: Hello,
For start I'm assuming the chessboard will always be in view. There is only one 2D view, the one that the browser / plugin / application renders, as it's a screenshot of a computer-generated chessboard. No piece will ever be hidden, and the 'capture system' is my monitor taking screenshots, there are no lenses / cameras etc.

Comment: Wow. Well, if these are not natural images, the problem is greatly simplified: they probably have a small and fixed set of colors, so you can trivially threshold them to black and white. What I would do then is to "crop" and analyze the squares one by one, identify and discard the empty ones in the obvious way (their pixels are all the  same), and do some simple template matching against the known shapes of the pieces. Even if the interior of the piece images provide no information, you need not identify the edges, since the 2D shapes themselves are discriminative enough.

Answer (score 0):

Salut Andrei,

I have done a coin counting algorithm from a picture so the process should be helpful. 
The algorithm is called Generalized Hough transform

1. Make the picture black and white, it is easier that way
2. Take the image from 1 piece and "slide it over the screenshot"
3. For each cell you calculate the nr of common pixel in the 2 images
4. Where you have the largest number there you have the piece

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would do the same, since your objects always look the same. Take a screenshot for every piece, hard code the pattern (for example as bitmap), and then do a simple sum of errors. The lowest error wins (ideally it really should be 0). Should be really easy (and yes, B&W image, preferably with no sharing is easiest).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah go with Salut Andrei,

1. Convert the picture into greyscale
2. Slice into 64 squares and store in array
3. Using Mat lab can identify the pieces easily
4. Color can be obtained from Calculating the percentage of No. dot pixels(black pixels)
   threshold=no.black pixels /no. of black pixels + no. of white pixels,
   If ur value is above threshold then WHITE else BLACK

Comment: This won't work because you wouldn't know the colour of the pieces.

Answer (score -1):

I'm working on a similar project in c# finding which piece is which isn't the hard part for me. First step is to find a rectangle that shows just the board and cuts everything else out. I first hard-coded it to search for the colors of the squares but would like to make it more robust and reliable regardless of the color scheme. Trying to make it find squares of pixels that match within a certain threshold and extrapolate the board location from that.